# Shoutbox: Best way to count users active

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a shoutbox which is coded in PHP and Javascript and uses MySQL.
It functions like this.. We have a refresh.txt file that checks for new shouts, if there is a new shout there is a call to the database to grab the new shouts.

Now as we all know the main problem with shoutboxs is the CPU usage.
So I was wondering if there was a way to count active users without it adding too much extra stress on the server.
Maybe via Javascript?

Unfortunately I do not have any source code to hand as it would be a new feature added in there.
Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these users logged in with a PHP session? If so, just [count the number of active session files](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/The-Quickest-Way-To-Count-Users-Online-With-PHP/1/) in the session save directory. That's not CPU-intensive and involves no database calls.

Further, if you're still avoiding database calls for this, you could have a private file keep track of the different clients (e.g. IP addresses) and when they last requested a resource from the server. More on this [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976362/show-live-user-count-on-website-with-google-analytics).However, if multiple users visit from the same network (e.g. schools or businesses) then you have a logical error, and the solution is to log individual users with cookies or sessions.

You may also be interested in [long polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) (Javascript). It keeps a connection open with the server and occasionally checks to see if there's new data. This can be useful when counting the number of active users without, per-se, sessions or cookies.

Comment: That is a very interesting answer.. I going to start looking at these options now.. We don't have a sessions directory I am using SMF for the forums.. not 100% how that would work.. I think there sessions are stored in the database. The ideal solution is to be-able to get a list of users who are online.

Main reason I want todo this is because the forums only store who is online in the last 15 mins.. But I know that there is alot more online. Would be good to see who actually is online.

Comment: Simple Machine's online user (and guest) count is fairly accurate from my experience. If you still want your own, I can relate. For a family website I built a shoutbox feature that was AJAX-powered, from scratch (with jQuery). If there was only one user online, it didn't poll at all, saving resources. The more users that were online, the more it polled (never more often than every 10 seconds). Each time a user loaded a page it updated their last activity time in a database. I've found this to be efficient for smaller projects. I learned a lot, too.

Answer (score 1):

Simply have an activity counter. Just count anyone who was active in the last 4 minutes. Then use JS to request that number every 10 seconds from your server.

Otherwise, I'd rather just use a 3rd party product like http://www.shoutmix.com

Comment: I like this answer aswell. Do a call every 4 minutes and have that displayed in an online list.. Sounds viable and wouldn't be that intensive. I am using SMF so I could have it use the SSI and call the who_is which would then log them as online.. Then I would still need a stat counter in JS for the actual number online in the shoutbox to be displayed..