# Using AJAX to confirm visitor activity?

Tags: php, ajax, android-activity

I'd like to enable my visitors to see how many people are currently connected to the same page as them (it's an interactive javascript page). So if there were 2 users, it would show to both users:

Users connected: 2

Since all users are constantly sending ajax requests to the server (every 1s), I thought there must be a good way to take advantage of that.

I'm guessing I should write some sort of a script that logs these ajax requests and writes to the database the number of **different** ajax requests it is currently getting.

But I'm not exactly sure how to implement this...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976362/show-live-user-count-on-website-with-google-analytics Be wary that multiple sessions using the same file at once might cause race conditions. It would be better to keep track using a database manager such as MySQL.

Comment: Tried putting the script on my site, it made the users.txt and all, but it didnt show 2 users connected when there were 2 users on it :(

Answer (score 1):

Insert session id into db when user visits your site, make a php file which counts number of rows, then ping that file using `setInterval()` function..

Comment: This would work if I was trying to make a total visitor counter. But I need to decrement user count whenever a user is not active anymore.

Comment: You can add a column named time and when you can add a statement to delete all rows where the value is greater than `time()-600` i.e 10 mins range, plus you never track activity accurately, like what if the client closes the tab rather than logging out?